# Qt Plugins with external libraries

Tags: dll, qtplugin

I'm  devellopping a QT application with QT Plugins.
my plugins need external libraries(.dll) to run. I want to put all my plugins in a "plugins" folder in a folder for each plugin. In each folder I want to put the librairies link to the plugin. At this moment, I must put all libraries of all plugins next to the executable of my application.

Have you any idea to give the path of the plugin external application to the main application?